# Why it takes long time to open a map page

Tags: leaflet

While opening for the first time it takes more than 30 minutes to open this map page. What might be the reasons. Any suggestions from experienced professionals?

The link is http://ngiip.gov.np/THEMATIC_MAPS/TestPopden.html

Complete html is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Population Density</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="POPCEN/Popcen.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol/master/src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js"></script>
<script src="POPCEN/districtar.js"></script>
<script src="POPCEN/zonesar.js"></script>
<script src="POPCEN/regionsar.js"></script>
<script src="COMMON/nepalar.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="POPCEN/Popcen.css" />

  <script src="POPCEN/districtpt.js"></script>
  <script src="POPCEN/districtar.js"></script>
  <script src="COMMON/roads.js"></script>
  <script src="COMMON/maintrail.js"></script>
  <script src="COMMON/nepalar.js"></script>
  <script src="COMMON/riversln.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="span9" style="height:100%">
    <div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 5; bottom: 5; left: 5;
            right: 5; z-index: 9999; width: 99%; height: 98%">
          <div id="button-information">
              <input type="button" id="btnSummary" value="Summary" onclick="mySummary()" class="btnStyle span2" />
              <input type="button" id="btnZoomToNepal" value="Zoom To Nepal" onclick="myzoom()"   class="btnStyle span2"  />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<script>
    function mySummary()
    {
    var w=window.open();
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write('<title>Summary</title>');
    w.document.write('<p><font size="5">Population Density:</p></font>');
    w.document.write('<p><font size="4">Population density is an effective index to measure the pressure of population on  land. The population per square kilometer of area measures the population density.</p></font>');
    w.document.write('<p><font size="4">Population density for administrative divisions has been presented in the  map.</p></font>');
    w.document.write('<p><font size="4">The population Census 2011 had shown the population density of Nepal was  180 persons per square kilometer. At district level, Manang had the lowest population density (3 persons) and Katmandu had  the highest population density (4416 persons).</p></font>');
    w.document.write('<p><font size="4">At Zone level, Bagmati had the highest population density (408 persons) and  Karnali had the lowest (18 persons).</p></font>');
    w.document.write('<p><font size="4">Similarly, for the Development Region level, Central Development Region had the  highest population density (352) and Mid-Western Development Region had the lowest (84).</p></font>');
    w.document.close();
    }
    function myzoom()
    {
             map.setView(new L.LatLng(28.1, 84.1), 7);
    }
</script>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, maxZoom: 12}).setView([28.1,84.1], 7);
      new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'bottomright' }).addTo(map);
      var mapnikUrl='http://{s}.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
      var mapnikAttrib='Reference Map Data &copy; <a href="http://{s}.www.toolserver.org">Mapnik Tiles</a>';
      var noneAttrib='Nepal Map &copy <a href="http://www.dos.gov.np/" target="_blank">Survey Department</a>, Census Data  &copy <a href="http://www.cbs.gov.np/" target="_blank">CBS</a>, Nepal';
      var none = new L.tileLayer('', {attribution: noneAttrib});
      var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/64f775cf62f14b1083e24625d21b23a9/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
      var osmAttrib='Reference Map Data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
      var googleAttrib='Reference Map Data &copy; <a href="http://google.org">GoogleRoadMap</a>';
      none.addTo(map);

    var infonep = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
    infonep.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infonep'); // create a div with a class "infonep"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    infonep.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Nepal Population Information:</h4>' + '<hr>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + 'NEPAL' + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Population: ' + props.POP68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Male Population: ' + props.MALE68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Female Population: ' + props.FEMALE68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Area (Sq. Km.): ' + props.AREA_SQKM + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + '<b>' + 'Population Density: ' + props.POPDEN68 + ' people / Sq.Km.<sup>2</sup>' + '</b>'
            : 'Move mouse over the country');
    };
    infonep.addTo(map);

    var info = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };
    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Population Information By Districts:</h4>' + '<hr>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + 'District: ' + props.DNAME + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Population: ' + props.POP68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Male Population: ' + props.MALE68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Female Population: ' + props.FEMALE68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Area (Sq. Km.): ' + props.AREA_SQKM + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + '<b>' + 'Population Density: ' + props.POPDEN68 + ' people / Sq.Km.<sup>2</sup>' + '</b>'
            : 'Move mouse over a district');
    };
    var info1 = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
    info1.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info1'); // create a div with a class "info1"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    var dislegend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
    dislegend.onAdd = function (map) {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 50, 100, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 4420],
            labels = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            div.innerHTML += 
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : ' +' +
                '<br>' + '<b>' + 'DISTRICTWISE POPULATION DENSITY' + '</b>' + '</br>' +
                '...............(people per sq. km.)...............');
        }
        return div;
    };


    function stylenep(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.POPDEN68),
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '2',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
    }

        var popNep = new L.geoJson(nepalar, {
            style: stylenep,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var defaultStyle = layer.style,
                that = this;//NEW
            layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                weight: 3,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
                });
                infonep.update(layer.feature.properties);
            });
            layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                popNep.resetStyle(e.target); //NEW
                infonep.update();
            });
            }
            });
            map.addLayer(popNep);

    function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000  ? '#662506' :
               d > 800  ? '#993404' :
               d > 600  ? '#CC4C02' :
               d > 400  ? '#EC7014' :
               d > 200   ? '#FE9929' :
               d > 100   ? '#FEC44F' :
               d > 50   ? '#FEE391' :
                          '#FFFFE5';
    }
    function styledist(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.POPDEN68),
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#000000',
            dashArray: '2',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
    }

        var popDist = new L.geoJson(districtar, {
            style: styledist,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var defaultStyle = layer.style,
                that = this;//NEW
            layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.setStyle({
                weight: 3,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
                });
                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            });
            layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                popDist.resetStyle(e.target); //NEW
                info.update();
            });
            }
            });

    L.LabelOverlay = L.Class.extend({
            initialize: function(/*LatLng*/ latLng, /*String*/ label, options) {
                this._latlng = latLng;
                this._label = label;
                L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
        },
        options: {
                offset: new L.Point(0, 2)
        },
        onAdd: function(map) {
                this._map = map;
                if (!this._container) {
                        this._initLayout();
                }
                map.getPanes().overlayPane.appendChild(this._container);
                this._container.innerHTML = this._label;
                map.on('viewreset', this._reset, this);
                this._reset();
        },
        onRemove: function(map) {
                map.getPanes().overlayPane.removeChild(this._container);
                map.off('viewreset', this._reset, this);
        },
        _reset: function() {
                var pos = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng);
                var op = new L.Point(pos.x + this.options.offset.x, pos.y - this.options.offset.y);
                L.DomUtil.setPosition(this._container, op);
        },
        _initLayout: function() {
                this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-label-overlay3');
        }
    });

var  saptari = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.6067351, 86.7473707), '<b>SAPTARI</b>'),
     jhapa = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.5777816, 87.9120188), '<b>JHAPA</b>'),
     sunsari = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.6376799, 87.1631739), '<b>SUNSARI</b>'),
     morang = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.6110406, 87.4644603), '<b>MORANG</b>'),
     siraha = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.7439735, 86.3414066), '<b>SIRAHA</b>'),
     dhanusha = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.7716145, 86.0334886), '<b>DHANUSHA</b>'),
     ilam = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.8852608, 87.8920930), '<b>ILAM</b>'),
     mahottari = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.9648904, 85.8319702), '<b>MAHOTTARI</b>'),
     udayapur = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.8686769, 86.6487705), '<b>UDAYAPUR</b>'),
     sarlahi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.9426485, 85.5687022), '<b>SARLAHI</b>'),
     dhankuta = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(26.9525622, 87.3311950), '<b>DHANKUTA</b>'),
     rautahat = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.0649710, 85.3229358), '<b>RAUTAHAT</b>'),
     terhathum = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.1688178, 87.5476898), '<b>TERHATHUM</b>'),
     bara = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.0427584, 85.0409276), '<b>BARA</b>'),
     sindhuli = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.2117605, 85.9308228), '<b>SINDHULI</b>'),
     parsa = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.2581936, 84.8065190), '<b>PARSA</b>'),
     khotang = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.1595703, 86.7861487), '<b>KHOTANG</b>'),
     bhojpur = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.1743310, 87.0863670), '<b>BHOJPUR</b>'),
     panchthar = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.1187149, 87.8036754), '<b>PANCHTHAR</b>'),
     okhaldhunga = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.3376810, 86.4456043), '<b>OKHALDHUNGA</b>'),
     lalitpur = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.5489654, 85.3363697), '<b>LALITPUR</b>'),
     makawanpur = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.4376176, 85.0875452), '<b>MAKAWANPUR</b>'),
     bhaktapur = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.6744837, 85.4386864), '<b>BHAKTAPUR</b>'),
     kabhrepalanchok = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.5453520, 85.6367481), '<b>KABHREPALANCHOK</b>'),
     rupandehi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.5501214, 83.4176916), '<b>RUPANDEHI</b>'),
     kapilbastu = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.6144825, 82.9665011), '<b>KAPILBASTU</b>'),
     kathmandu = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.7424391, 85.3357188), '<b>KATHMANDU</b>'),
     ramechhap = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.3952187, 86.1206839), '<b>RAMECHHAP</b>'),
     nawalparasi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.6293379, 83.9110274), '<b>NAWALPARASI</b>'),
     chitawan = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.5782314, 84.4645971), '<b>CHITAWAN</b>'),
     palpa = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.8110945, 83.6317023), '<b>PALPA</b>'),
     sankhuwasabha = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.5492191, 87.2599972), '<b>SANKHUWASABHA</b>'),
     taplejung = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.6105047, 87.8232425), '<b>TAPLEJUNG</b>'),
     nuwakot = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.8949822, 85.2324457), '<b>NUWAKOT</b>'),
     arghakhanchi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.9079787, 83.1237079), '<b>ARGHAKHANCHI</b>'),
     tanahu = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.9351018, 84.2494866), '<b>TANAHU</b>'),
     solukhumbu = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.6846062, 86.7379162), '<b>SOLUKHUMBU</b>'),
     dolakha = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.8239353, 86.2195393), '<b>DOLAKHA</b>'),
     sindhupalchok = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.9045368, 85.7532630), '<b>SINDHUPALCHOK</b>'),
     syangja = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.0095907, 83.8219656), '<b>SYANGJA</b>'),
     gulmi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.0955638, 83.3135873), '<b>GULMI</b>'),
     dang = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.9314075, 82.4501670), '<b>DANG</b>'),
     dhading = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(27.8799525, 84.8850669), '<b>DHADING</b>'),
     banke = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.0972276, 81.8454680), '<b>BANKE</b>'),
     pyuthan = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.1201159, 82.8434016), '<b>PYUTHAN</b>'),
     rasuwa = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.1687820, 85.3503115), '<b>RASUWA</b>'),
     parbat = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.2239708, 83.7224743), '<b>PARBAT</b>'),
     lamjung = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.2840180, 84.4405411), '<b>LAMJUNG</b>'),
     rolpa = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.3122228, 82.6249230), '<b>ROLPA</b>'),
     kaski = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.3459566, 83.9878150), '<b>KASKI</b>'),
     baglung = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.3392462, 83.2075859), '<b>BAGLUNG</b>'),
     salyan = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.4072634, 82.1600338), '<b>SALYAN</b>'),
     bardiya = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.3715290, 81.4145904), '<b>BARDIYA</b>'),
     gorkha = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.2730791, 84.8087532), '<b>GORKHA</b>'),
     myagdi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.5472800, 83.4855776), '<b>MYAGDI</b>'),
     manang = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.6727160, 84.1794796), '<b>MANANG</b>'),
     rukum = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.7019749, 82.6476446), '<b>RUKUM</b>'),
     surkhet = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.6016676, 81.5781864), '<b>SURKHET</b>'),
     kailali = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.7313405, 80.8788673), '<b>KAILALI</b>'),
     jajarkot = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.8692170, 82.1990124), '<b>JAJARKOT</b>'),
     dailekh = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.8846144, 81.6689055), '<b>DAILEKH</b>'),
     kanchanpur = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.8449942, 80.3081700), '<b>KANCHANPUR</b>'),
     mustang = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(28.9487956, 83.8662775), '<b>MUSTANG</b>'),
     achham = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.1129637, 81.2961528), '<b>ACHHAM</b>'),
     dadeldhura = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.2106008, 80.4842253), '<b>DADELDHURA</b>'),
     kalikot = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.2165796, 81.7420471), '<b>KALIKOT</b>'),
     doti = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.1675085, 80.8913545), '<b>DOTI</b>'),
     jumla = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.2388493, 82.2182243), '<b>JUMLA</b>'),
     dolpa = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.2149801, 83.0358120), '<b>DOLPA</b>'),
     baitadi = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.5088079, 80.5747052), '<b>BAITADI</b>'),
     bajura = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.5239169, 81.5649464), '<b>BAJURA</b>'),
     mugu = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.5887127, 82.4442784), '<b>MUGU</b>'),
     bajhang = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.6862265, 81.1968249), '<b>BAJHANG</b>'),
     darchula = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(29.8704921, 80.8135036), '<b>DARCHULA</b>'),
     humla = new L.LabelOverlay(new L.LatLng(30.0263851, 81.8774725), '<b>HUMLA</b>');
    var districtname = L.layerGroup([saptari, jhapa, sunsari, morang, siraha, dhanusha, ilam, mahottari, udayapur, sarlahi,      dhankuta, rautahat, terhathum, bara, sindhuli, parsa, khotang, bhojpur, panchthar, okhaldhunga, lalitpur, makawanpur,      bhaktapur, kabhrepalanchok, rupandehi, kapilbastu, kathmandu, ramechhap, nawalparasi, chitawan, palpa,          sankhuwasabha, taplejung, nuwakot, arghakhanchi, tanahu, solukhumbu, dolakha, sindhupalchok, syangja, gulmi, dang,      dhading, banke, pyuthan, rasuwa, parbat, lamjung, rolpa, kaski, baglung, salyan, bardiya, gorkha, myagdi, manang,     rukum,  surkhet, kailali, jajarkot, dailekh, kanchanpur, mustang, achham, dadeldhura, kalikot, doti, jumla, dolpa, baitadi,     bajura,  mugu, bajhang, darchula, humla]);
        var labelMarkerOptions = {
            radius: 0,
            fillColor: "#000000",
            color: "#000000",
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0,
            fillOpacity: 0
        };

        var dist_Name = L.geoJson(districtpt, {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                        return L.circleMarker(latlng, labelMarkerOptions);
                }
        });

        var road = L.geoJson(roads, {
            style: function(feature) {
                switch (feature.properties.ROADCLASS) {
                    case 'NationalHighway': return {color: "#000000", weight: 1.5, opacity: 1, fillColor: "#FFFF00", fillOpacity: 1};
                    case 'SecondaryRoad': return {color: "#FF0000", weight: 1.5, opacity: 1, fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity:  0.2};
                    case 'OtherRoad': return {color: "#000000", weight: 1, opacity: 1, fillColor: "#000000", fillOpacity: 0.2};
                }
            }
        });
        var trailStyle = {
            "color": "#000000",
            "weight": 2,
            "opacity": 0.65
        };
        var mtrail = L.geoJson(maintrail, {
            style: trailStyle
        });

        var riverStyle = {
            "color": "#0000FF",
            "weight": 1,
            "opacity": 0.65
        };
        var river = L.geoJson(riversln, {
            style: riverStyle,
              onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.RIV_NAME);
      }
        });

        var river1Style = {
            "color": 'transparent',
            "weight": 10,
            "opacity": 0.65
        };
        var river1 = L.geoJson(riversln, {
            style: river1Style,
              onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.RIV_NAME);
      }
        });

        var mapnikBase   = new L.tileLayer(mapnikUrl, {attribution: mapnikAttrib + ' ' + noneAttrib});
        var osmBase   = new L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib + ' ' + noneAttrib});
        var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP', {attribution: googleAttrib + ' ' + noneAttrib});
        var none   = new L.tileLayer('', {attribution: noneAttrib});
        var baseMaps = {
      "Mapnik Base Map": mapnikBase,
      "OSM Base Map": osmBase,
      "Google Base Map": googleLayer,
      "Turn Off Base Map": none,
        };

      var groupedOverlays = {
        "AdminDivisions": {
            "Nepal Population": popNep,
            "District Population": popDist
        },
        "Annotations": {
            "District Name": dist_Name
        },
        "Roads and River": {
            "Road Network": road,
            "Main Trail": mtrail,
            "Main Rivers(Click to display name)": river
        }
      };

       L.control.groupedLayers(baseMaps, groupedOverlays, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

    map.on ('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
     if (eventLayer.name === 'Nepal Population') {
         infonep.addTo(map);
     } else if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population') {
         info.addTo(map);
               dislegend.addTo(map);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'District Name') {
               this.addLayer(districtname);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Road Network') {
         road.addTo(this);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Main Trail') {
         mtrail.addTo(this);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Main Rivers(Click to display name)') {
         river1.addTo(this);
         river.addTo(this);
      } else {
     }
    });
    map.on ('overlayremove', function (eventLayer) {
      if (eventLayer.name === 'Nepal Population') {
         map.removeControl(infonep);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population') {
         map.removeControl(info);
         map.removeControl(dislegend);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'District Name') {
               map.removeLayer(districtname);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Road Network') {
         map.removeLayer(road);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Main Trail') {
         map.removeLayer(mtrail);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'Main Rivers(Click to display name)') {
         map.removeLayer(river1);
         map.removeLayer(river);
      } else {
     }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing you have to do is to erase the line 10 from your code:

```
https: //rawgithub.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol/master/src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js
```

That's **not only** because you've already loaded `leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js` at line 9, but because **you can significantly‎ reduce** the page loading time!

I'll tell you how did I found that, hoping that in the future you'll use (and improve) this simple technique:

1) I've checked the address you've provided. On my computer it takes only 10 seconds to see the page on my screen. (You said something about 30 minutes, but I'm sure that's a mistake.)

2) Because I'm using Chrome, I've pressed `Ctrl + Shift + I` to open the `Developer Tools`.
First thought was to perform a *full network and web page audit*:

[image]

3) After the audit was ready, going to the Network tab, I've had the big picture:

[image]

4) Now, don't be too enthusiastic! Only by removing that time costly line, this doesn't means that your problems have gone. You have a lot of problems to handle, as you can see:

[image]

[image]

The `audit` report is too long to be expanded here, but I think you've got the idea. Only by removing errors and testing again and again you'll obtain a web page satisfactory loading speed.

Comment: Quick response acknowledged. I will continue to learn more in this regard.

Comment: Now, in another similar case, I have gzip file(9 MB) in same location as uncompressed js (27 MB) file. And added following lines "<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>" to my .htaccess file. Why I am not able to open gzipped (*.js.gz) file? Sorin (or others) any suggestions?

Comment: I rather think this is more a new question than a comment on my answer, so that I believe it's better for you to ask a new question, with more details about what you've done already and where you got stuck. In this way you will get more exposure for your problem and most users will get a chance to respond. And beside all the above, I really don't have enough space in the tiny space of a comment the give you a proper answer, with text and code formatting and image captures.

Comment: appreciate your suggestion.